# What is the format of an authors file for git svn, specifically for special characters like backslash or underscore?

Tags: git, git-svn, codeplex

I am trying to clone [Papercut, an smtp server emulator](http://papercut.codeplex.com/)

I'm getting the list of SVN authors with `svn log -q https://papercut.svn.codeplex.com/svn | grep -e '^r'| awk 'BEGIN {FS="|"};{print $2}'|sort|uniq` which is giving me

```
RNO\_MCLWEB
SND\krobertson_cp
```

I created an authors.txt with the `SVN_User = UserName <Email>` format, but when I run

```
git svn clone --no-metadata -A authors.txt https://papercut.svn.codeplex.com/svn papercut
```

it complains "Author: RNO\_MCLWEB not defined in authors.txt file"

I've tried with putting a \ before the '\' and '_' to try to escape them, and adding quotes around the name, but neither worked.

I can't find any better description of the authors.txt file format than `SVN_User = UserName <Email>`

Comment: Type `git svn clone -help` and look for the `-A` option for a good description about the `authors.txt` file.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I hate to be "that guy", but I just gave it a try and it worked fine for me. Here's the copy of the authors file I used:

```
RNO\_MCLWEB = Ronald McDonald <dude@example.com>
SND\krobertson_cp = Some Guy <someone@example.com>
```

I did, however, use a slightly different method than you did to generate author names, following [these directions](http://progit.org/book/ch8-2.html). My specific incantation was:

```
$ svn log --xml | grep author | sort -u | perl -pe 's/.>(.?)<./$1 = /'
```

I'm also using Git 1.6.6.1 (doubt that makes a difference, but you never know).

I did notice that when I used your pipeline to get the SVN authors, there were spaces in front of their SVN usernames in the resulting file (i.e., there was a space in column 1 on each line). Don't know if that makes a difference or not.

Comment: The first time I made the authors.txt, I didn't put a string like a@b.com for the email, just <MCLWEB>
I guess that was the problem, since an authors.txt with the text you showed did clone without a problem (git 1.6.5.1).  I thought I had tried with proper email addresses, but apparently not.

Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Regex is incorrect - it needs to match more than 1 char. Fixed: `'s/.*>(.*?)<.*/$1 = /'`

Answer (score 17):

I had same problem, but with user apache.
In authors file a had line like this.

```
apache = Apache
```

or

```
apache = Apache <>
```

But when I set it to

```
apache = Apache <noreply@something.com>
```

My repo started cloned normaly.
Please be sure that you set all you authors names and email correctly, with follow format

```
svn_user_name = JustNameInGit <obligatory@email.com>
```

Every field is obligatory!!!

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11579311/168775) for a similar discussion.

Comment: Noting that every field is obligatory helped me. The link from eykanal implies that it isn't which seems to be true in the case he linked, not during an SVN import.

Answer (score 3):

I used the following which helps skip messages with words like 'authorization' in them

```
svn log --xml | grep /author | sort -u | perl -pe 's/.>(.?)<./$1 = /' > users.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue, it turned out to be the file encoding in my example.  Make sure the text file is saved at UTF-8

You can do this in any good text edit (eg notepad++ Encoding menu)

Comment: This solved it for me as well.  The file was originally generated by the atlassian svn migration script from within powershell on windows 10, and it was UTF-16.  I saved as UTF-8 and it worked.