# GIT commit as different user without email / or only email

Tags: git, commit

I'm trying to commit some changes as a different user, but i do not have a valid email address, following command is not working for me:

```
git commit --author="john doe" -m "some fix"
fatal: No existing author found with 'john doe'
```

I have the same problem when trying to commit with only an email address

```
git commit --author="john@doe.com" -m "some fix"
fatal: No existing author found with 'john@doe.com'
```

On the GIT man pages for the commit command it says i can use the

```
standard A U Thor <author@example.com> format
```

For the --author option.

Where is this format defined ?
what does A and U stand for ? how do i commit for a different user with only a username or only an email?

Comment: *A U* doesn't stand for anything, it's just an example: *A U Thor* => *AUThor* => *Author*. You can specify anything you want as a name.

Comment: I know that A U Thor forms Author, i was wondering if there was any significance in the separation.

Comment: Related: [Can I specify multiple users for myself in .gitconfig?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220416/can-i-specify-multiple-users-for-myself-in-gitconfig).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The

> *standard* A U Thor <author@example.com> format

Seems to be defined as followed: 
( as far as i know, with absolutely no warranty )

A U Thor = **required username**

- The separation of the characters *probably* indicates that spaces are allowed, it could also be resembling initials.
- The username has to be followed by 1 space, extra spaces will be truncated

<author@example.com> = **optional email address**

- Must always be between < > signs.
- The email address format isn't validated, you can pretty much enter whatever you want
- Optional, you can omit this explicitly by using <>

If you don't use this exact syntax, git will search through the existing commits and use the first commit that contains your provided string.

**Examples:**

1. Only user name

   Omit the email address explicitly:

   ```
   git commit --author="John Doe <>" -m "Impersonation is evil."
   ```
2. Only email

   Technically this isn't possible. You can however enter the email address as the username and explicitly omit the email address. This doesn't seem like it's very useful.
   I think it would make even  more sense to extract the user name from the email address and then use that as the username. But if you have to:

   ```
   git commit --author="john@doe.com <>" -m "Impersonation is evil."
   ```

I ran in to this when trying to convert a repository from mercurial to git.
I tested the commands on msysgit 1.7.10.

Answer (score 193):

The minimal required author format, as hinted to in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8992149/168775), is

```
Name <email>
```

In your case, this means you want to write

```
git commit --author="Name <email>" -m "whatever"
```

Per Willem D'Haeseleer's comment, if you don't have an email address, you can use `<>`:

```
git commit --author="Name <>" -m "whatever"
```

As written on the [`git commit` man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html) that you linked to, if you supply anything less than that, it's used as a search token to search through previous commits, looking for other commits by that author.

Comment: Just found out that if you don't have an email address you can also just type  "name <>" , to explicitly leave it blank instead of entering bogus.

Comment: If you'd use `"name <>"`, and `git commit --amend` after, it will fail with `invalid ident` error; so just don't

Comment: Apparently even when using that option, you still need to have set user.email and user.name in your git config, otherwise git complains.

Comment: How do I add a file as a different user for my first commit ? I will use the commit command after that.

Answer (score 68):

The specific format is:

```
git commit --author="John Doe <john@doe.com>" -m "Impersonation is evil."
```

Comment: Why doesn't it require password of John Doe if you commit for his name?

Comment: @Narek What would that be in this context?

Comment: This apparently no longer works? On `git version 2.43.0` I get "Committer identity unknown"

Answer (score 49):

The `--author` option doesn't bypass reading the invoking user's personality:

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

This does:

```
git -c user.name='A U Thor' -c user.email=author@example.com commit
```

---

Tip: For the purpose of separating work- and private git personalities, Git 2.13 supports [directory specific configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60344116): You no longer need to wrap git with these options to get that.

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me. Note the order is important. `git commit -c user.name="j bloggs" -am "message"` gives an error `fatal: Option -m cannot be combined with -c/-C/-F`

Comment: @Martin Yes, because the ```-c``` flag pertains to the ```git``` command proper and not the ```commit``` subcommand (which btw has a different ```-c``` flag)

Comment: This is the real answer. The rest suggesting --author are not helpful at all because user name and email are still required.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I am on GitHub Codespaces, where several different users could in principle use the same shell to make commits. Setting the global or repository author is thus prone to misattributing the individual commit author. Setting `-c user.name` inline is preferable, and this is the only way to do it.

Comment: It looks like I'm mistaken! `git -c ...` **will write those inputs to ~/.gitconfig** i.e. it's having the same effect as running `git config --global`. To get a temporary user, then, it seems we'd need to follow up this command by then deleting the entries from ~/.gitconfig.

Answer (score 13):

Just supplement：

> git commit --author="john@doe.com " -m "Impersonation is evil."

In some cases the commit still fails and shows you the following message:

> *** Please tell me who you are.
>
> Run
>
> git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
>    git config --global user.name "Your Name"
>
> to set your account's default identity.
>   Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
>
> fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got  xxxx)

So just run "git config", then "git commit"

Comment: This is what I needed. I have separate username and email for a corporate GitHub and the public GitHub. I needed to set my current repo to use my public GitHub username and email so that I could push my changes without exposing a private email.

Answer (score 9):

Format

```
A U Thor <author@example.com>
```

simply mean that you should specify

```
FirstName MiddleName LastName <email@example.com>
```

Looks like middle and last names are optional (maybe the part before email doesn't have a strict format at all). Try, for example, this:

```
git commit --author="John <john@doe.com>" -m "some fix"
```

As the docs say:

```
  --author=<author>
       Override the commit author. Specify an explicit author using the standard 
       A U Thor <author@example.com> format. Otherwise <author> is assumed to 
       be a pattern and is used to search for an existing commit by that author 
       (i.e. rev-list --all -i --author=<author>); the commit author is then copied 
       from the first such commit found.
```

if you don't use this format, git treats provided string as a pattern and tries to find matching name among the authors of other commits.

Comment: There's no such thing as *FirstName MiddleName LastName*. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579311/git-commit-as-different-user-without-email-or-only-email#comment15320898_11579311).

Answer (score 6):

```
git -c "user.name={{ name }}" -c "user.email={{ email }}" commit -m "{{ message }}"
```

where {{ }} indicates YOU put the value

Answer (score 1):

Open Git Bash.

Set a Git username:

$ git config --global user.name "name family"
Confirm that you have set the Git username correctly:

$ git config --global user.name

> name family

Set a Git email:

$ git config --global user.email email@foo.com
Confirm that you have set the Git email correctly:

$ git config --global user.email

> email@foo.com

Answer (score 1):

It is all dependent on how you commit.

For example:

`git commit -am "Some message"`

will use your `~\.gitconfig` username. In other words, if you open that file you should see a line that looks like this:

```
[user]
    email = someemail@gmail.com
```

That would be the email you want to change. If your doing a pull request through Bitbucket or Github etc. you would be whoever you're logged in as.

Answer (score 0):

An *alternative* if the concern is to hide the real email address...If you are committing to Github you don't need a real email you can use `<username>@users.noreply.github.com`

Regardless of using Github or not, you probably first want change your **committer** details (on windows use `SET GIT_...`)

```
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME='username' 
GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL='username@users.noreply.github.com'
```

Then set the author

```
git commit --author="username <username@users.noreply.github.com>"
```

https://help.github.com/articles/keeping-your-email-address-private

Comment: Unlike all of the other solutions, this works when you haven't initialized user.email/user.name initially.