# How to push to remote repo under another user

Tags: git, github

I check this question about commit under another author [git commit as different user without email / or only email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579311/git-commit-as-different-user-without-email-or-only-email)
How can I also push to remote repo under another login. I do:

```
git commit --author="notMe" -m "whatever"
git push https://<remote-repo>
Username for 'https://github.com': notMe
Password for 'https://qRoman@github.com': <notMe's password>
```

But as result I got this: [image: commit & push result]
How can I commit & push like another author?

---

**UPD:** I tried `git config user.name "notMe"` and result is:
[image: result]
It's almost what I want but why my avatar is still here?

Comment: Have you specified the "author" in the format of "Name <email>"?

Comment: No, just name as specified in question. Will try with email soon.

Comment: "why my avatar is still here?" --- because your email is still there. Check the changeset details.

Comment: @zerkms, yes, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify both the name and the email of the author of a commit to entirely vanish traces of your current account.

Answer (score 2):

You created the commit as the author "notMe" but pushed using the current user for that repo (which is Alendorff).
You can change the user for that repo by :

```
git config user.name "Billy Everyteen"
```

You can also check the current user for a repo by :

```
git config user.name
```

More can be found [here](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/)

Comment: "but pushed using the default user" --- what does this mean?

Comment: by default user, I meant the user currently set for that repo (which is Alendorff)

Comment: Well, if you check the question once again you will see, that OP put the credentials of another user specifically for the push operation.