# add files to Github with considering it in user contribution

Tags: git, github, commit

I have some 5000 lines of code that I want to add to my Github repository. But I don't want Github to consider those code as my contribution.

Is there a way I could add code to Github without it being considered as my contribution.

So even when I add these 5000 lines of code, Github should shown, my contribution as 0 lines of code.

Comment: What kind of code is it? Some dependency, or…?

Comment: If you wrote 5000 lines of value adding code, why _woudn't_ you want credit for it?  You could always amend the commits with a different username, and also push with a different GitHub account.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11579722/2303202 can override the author of commit. Then _maybe_ github will do what you need

Comment: @Ryan yes i want to commit dependencies.

Comment: @Chetan: You can mark them as vendored code with a `.gitattributes` file, then. That probably won’t count towards your stats. https://github.com/github/linguist#vendored-code (If it does, though, then you can also make the commit as a different author. Still do the `linguist-vendored` thing, though, as it affects other parts of GitHub.)